# Hyperledger Fabric - Identities for Organisations that don't Running Nodes

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, identity, ca

We have a use case where only a subset of consortium participants willing to run nodes. Other participants still want to submit transactions through a party that runs a node. How can we give identities for those parties and ensure their transactions will be included in the ledger through the existing nodes?

For example, say we have 4 parties `a.org`, `b.org`, `c.org`, and `d.org`. Parties `a.org` and `b.org` run nodes. Whereas party `c.org` plans to use party `a.org`'s nodes (similarly, `d.org` plans to use `b.org`'s nodes) to submit transactions with its own user identity, e.g., `user1.c.org`. Is this possible?

It's ok to run a CA for `c.org` and `d.org`. However, I'm looking for a better solution without wrapping `c.org` transactions within `a.org` transactions where it's signed by someone (or a node) in `a.org`. This is needed as someday `c.org` may decide to run a node and claim all their previous transactions.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly create the organization C MSP on the channel (using an organization C CA) and have organization C client users connect to organization A peers. Later, organization C can run their own peer if they like.